# Double integrals over general region -how to approach?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm in doubt on how to approach a problem of double integrals over a specific region.

I have to calculate $\int\int\limits_R e^x dA$, R being the region between $y=\frac{x}{2}$, $y=x$, $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and $y=\frac{2}{x}$. I am only interested in the first quadrant. That being said, the region is as follows:

[image]

And the points:

[image]

Where 1.414 is $\sqrt{2}$ and 0.707 is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

My approach, which I'm in doubt if it's a valid one, was the following:

Divide the region into 2 regions and consider each new region a ["case 2"](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIGeneralRegion.aspx) region and sum the integrals over each region to obtain the integral over the original region:

[image]

The division is made in order to obtain well-defined functions in each region. Is that a valid approach? If not, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: Looks good. Another way to approach this problem would be through a change of variables (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx).

Comment: @Adriano I never used change of variables with double integrals, I'll give it a try. A problem with the approach I was taking is that it leads to $\int e^\frac{1}{y} dy$, which I don't think should happen - http://i.imgur.com/sGDWrUa.jpg.

Comment: @Alex: I have been sorry not to make you an easier way to solve the finial integrals. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your approach looks just fine, is certainly valid, and it's clear you thought through the problem carefully. In a situation like this, another possible approach to consider would be using a [change of variables](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx).

Using a change of variables is one method we can use to integrate over one region, instead of breaking it into the sum of integrals over sub-regions. A good example to look through is the trapezoidal region discussed at the linked website, e.g.

Comment: A leading hint +1

Comment: Trying to suggest a potentially fruitful approach. The OP's *approach* and problem set up is picture-perfect, but leads to an unpleasant integral!

Comment: The same story is coming up when you use mine as well. :(

Answer (score 1):

Setting $$u=x/y,~~v=xy$$ you get easily that $$1\le u,v\le 2$$ and the main integrals will be changed to the following ones:

$$\int_1^2\int_1^2\exp(\sqrt{uv})|J|dudv$$ wherein $J$ is the [Jacobian determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html) $\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=1/2u$. It seems that the associated indefinite integral cannot be expressed by elementary functions.